# How can I open multiple windows/tabs in mobile iOS Safari with a single button click?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-chrome, safari

I have the following code that works just fine in Mac Safari (13.0.3 Catalina) for opening multiple tabs on a single click of a form button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function open_win() 
  {
     window.open("https://www.google.com/", "_new1");
     window.open("https://www.ebay.com/", "_new2");
     window.open("https://www.amazon.com/", "_new3");
  }
</script>

<form>
<input type=button value="Open Windows" onclick="open_win()">
</form>
```

The problem is, when I run it in Safari on iOS 13.2, it only opens the first tab. It also only opens the first tab in Mac Chrome and pop-up blocks the others.

Does anyone have a solution to solve this problem?

Comment: try allowing pop-up to show from browser settings.

Comment: The question is how to do it without the user needing to change their pop-up settings. That's why I'm opening it from the `onclick` function.

Comment: Of course. But if your browser doesn't give permission, I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Hi @EthanAllen - did you solve this issue? if yes, can you share it. Thanks

Comment: Nope no solution.